# AVCaptureSession preview screen orientation in iOS5

Tags: ios, ios5, orientation, avcapturesession, avcapture

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075300/avcapturevideopreviewlayer-orientation-need-landscape) a while back. I accepted the answer because it worked... until I tried it out on iOS5.

My app is landscape only. Opening the camera preview and holding the device with the home button on the right, the image in the preview appears 90 degees titled to the right. Once I take the picture, the captured image has the correct orientation. It's just the preview that is 90 degrees off. This fixes the issue for ios6:

```
AVCaptureConnection *previewLayerConnection=self.previewLayer.connection;

  if ([previewLayerConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
    [previewLayerConnection setVideoOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
```

But how can I fix this orientation issue for devices running iOS5? AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer connection is only available in iOS6.

Answer (score -1):

try AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.orientation