# Why a frame of a UIView is not updating in ViewDidLayoutSubviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, runtime, frame

I am trying to update the frame of a `UIView` which contains buttons and labels inside. I am trying to update it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (and I also tried in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`..). I want to change the y position (origin.y) of the view. 
The NSLogs says my original y position is 334, and after changing, it is 100. However, the position does not change in my view. I have already checked that the view is connected in the storyboard. What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    CGRect theFrame  = [self.bottomView frame];
    NSLog(@"Y position bottomview: %f", self.bottomView.frame.origin.y);

    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) //iPhone 4inch
    {
       // NSLog(@"iphone5");
    }
    else{
       // NSLog(@"iphone4");
        theFrame .origin.y =  100;
    }

    self.bottomView.frame = theFrame;
    NSLog(@"Y position bottomview after changing it: %f", self.bottomView.frame.origin.y);
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was related with Autolayout. However I couldn't turn it off since I am using autolayout in my project. I solved defining appropriate constraints in the view. Then there is no need to check if it is iPhone 4inch or 3.5inch and change the position of the frame since it automatically adapts to each size.

Answer (score 23):

I've had the same problem. Forcing the layouting for your view's superview helped me out:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.bottomView.superview setNeedsLayout];
    [self.bottomView.superview layoutIfNeeded];

    // Now modify bottomView's frame here
}
```

In Swift:

```swift
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    bottomView.superview!.setNeedsLayout()
    bottomView.superview!.layoutIfNeeded()

    // Now modify bottomView's frame here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lars, that was very useful! This solved a problem I had with one complex autolayout storyboard, where a particular view wasn't being resized by the time that didLayoutSubviews was called. Your solution forced the problem view to have the final size reported correctly in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: @Lars, Sadly, this didn't work for me. My problem is very similar to the OP.

I have a collection of views that I add to a container view. When these views are added, it adds it in the correct position, and whenever I remove it, it positions correctly.

However, as soon I as transition to a new screen from the nav bar, and the views get deallocated, so on viewDidLoad, I re-add them. Again, adding new views positions correctly but when I remove one, the position of the other views are NOT updated at all even though the frame location has been changed in viewDidLayoutSubviews. Thoughts?

Comment: @Setzer Check my answer

Comment: @Alsh - still doesn't work. The problem occurs when the view is un-loaded (navigating back to a previous screen then forward again) that the frame is not being updated immediately. I'm gonna try this constraints programmatically instead of frames unless there are other solutions

Answer (score 11):

Believe it or not the below code fixed it

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // UI changes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The frame setting should work in your code. But if the view has autolayout constraints (which I assume you have), your frame setting won't work. You can only go one way or the other (manual frame setting or autolayout), not both.