# Is it possible to autorotate AVPlayer even if the device turned on "Lock Portrait Orientation"?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, screen-orientation, avplayerviewcontroller

I want to play a video with `AVPlayerViewController()` from Apple's `AVKit framework`. well, the video plays nicely, auto rotate works well and rotate smoothly. But, is it possible to autorotate that (so it could rotate to landscape or rotate to portrait, not just one of it) even if the device turned on "Lock Portrait Orientation" ?

What i mean for `"Lock Portrait Orientation"` is the one from device's Control Center like this : [Lock Portrait Orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL84i.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer orientation - need landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075300/avcapturevideopreviewlayer-orientation-need-landscape)

Comment: I already open that link and its purpose is force the player to play landscape. What i look for is it's still flexible to change the orientation either landscape or portrait while turning on "Lock Portrait Orientation".

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?